# Joomla 1.6 language problem

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

In Joomla 1.6 all translation are now in double quotes " "

I would like to keep compatibility with 1.6 means that I would need two language files now
1. with double quotes for joomla 1.6
2. without for 1.5?

or is there a way to have only one language file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create separate language file for Joomla 1.5

Language file of Joomla 1.6 will work with both versions.

Comment: The problem is when you insert double quotes to language files Joomla 1.5 will show them everywhere.

Comment: I m using it without any issue. Did you try this?

Comment: but when you use special characters like ? or / than you will have to use double quotes.

Comment: I have used this `COM_COMPONENT_REGISTERATION_EMAIL="Quick ? Register"` and get the out put `Quick ? Register`

Comment: both in Joomla 1.6 and 1.5? I had tried and in Joomla 1.5 as output has "Quick ? Register" with ""

Answer (score 0):

To work in both versions, you must remove all special characters such as \ /!? & etc